# Schedule Multiple Arbitrary Events to WP Cron in WordPress

Tags: php, cron, wordpress

I'm trying to schedule multiple events with the WordPress Cron API with dynamically generated action names. Only one event could be added at a time with `add_action()` but not more than one.

With a plugin called [Cron View](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cron-view/), I could confirm that the events were registered but the function was not called somehow. I'm guessing that maybe the dynamically generated action names disappear in the next page load so WordPress cannot find them. I don't know.

The following code is ready to run as a plugin and demonstrates the problem. Any suggestion to solve this problem would be appreciated.

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Sample Cron Scheduler */

add_action('admin_menu', 'sample_cron_menu');
function sample_cron_menu() {
    add_options_page(
        'Sample Cron Scheduler', 
        'Sample Cron Scheduler', 
        'manage_options',
        'sample_cron_scheduler', 
        'sample_cron_scheduler_admin');
}
function sample_cron_scheduler_admin() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <?php
        // print the saved values
        echo '<h3>Saved values</h3>';
        print_r(get_option('crontest'));

        // do this ten times, meaning I want to register 10 events 
        $chars = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
        for ($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) {

            // generate a random string
            shuffle($chars);
            $randomstring = implode($chars);

            // schedule the next event
            // wp_schedule_single_event(time(), 'myeventaction');   // <-- this only runs one job
            add_action(sha1($randomstring),'myevent');              // so I want to add arbitrary multiple events but this doesn't work
            wp_schedule_single_event(time(), sha1($randomstring));                  
        }
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action('myeventaction', 'myevent'); 
function myevent() {    // this function just adds the current time to the option array

    $arr = get_option('crontest') ? get_option('crontest') : array();
    array_push($arr, date("M d Y H:i:s", time()));      // adds the current time at the end of the array
    array_splice($arr, 0, count($arr) - 20);            // reduce the number of elements to 20 to make it short
    update_option('crontest',  $arr);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess was right. WordPress did not remember the registered action names passed in `add_action()`. So I saved them in the option and retrieved them when the plugin loads and passing them all to `add_action()` solved it.

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Sample Cron Scheduler */

add_action('admin_menu', 'sample_cron_menu');
function sample_cron_menu() {
    add_options_page(
        'Sample Cron Scheduler', 
        'Sample Cron Scheduler', 
        'manage_options',
        'sample_cron_scheduler', 
        'sample_cron_scheduler_admin');
}
function sample_cron_scheduler_admin() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <?php
        // print the saved values
        echo '<h3>Saved values</h3>';
        echo '<h4>Actions</h4>';
        print_r(get_option('crontest_actions'));
        echo '<h4>Jobs</h4>';
        print_r(get_option('crontest'));

        // do this ten times, meaning I want to register 10 events 
        $arr = get_option('crontest_actions') ? get_option('crontest_actions') : array();
        $chars = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
        for ($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) {

            // generate a random string
            shuffle($chars);
            $randomstring = implode($chars);

            // schedule the next event
            $actionname = sha1($randomstring);
            array_push($arr, $actionname);
            add_action($actionname,'myevent');              // so I want to add arbitrary multiple events but this doesn't work
            wp_schedule_single_event(time(), $actionname);                  
        }
        update_option('crontest_actions', $arr);
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}

$actions = get_option('crontest_actions') ? get_option('crontest_actions') : array();
foreach($actions as $key => $action)    {
    add_action($action, 'myevent'); 
}

function myevent() {

    $arr = get_option('crontest') ? get_option('crontest') : array();
    array_push($arr, date("M d Y H:i:s", time()));      // adds the current time at the end of the array
    array_splice($arr, 0, count($arr) - 20);            // reduce the number of elements to 20 to make it short
    update_option('crontest',  $arr);

    $actions = get_option('crontest_actions') ? get_option('crontest_actions') : array();
    array_splice($actions, 0, 1);   // remove the first element
    update_option('crontest_actions',  $actions);
}

// use this to reset options
// $arr = array();
// update_option('crontest', $arr);
// update_option('crontest_actions', $arr);
```